# Trying to prevent invalid keypushes (not numbers) and multiple decimal points

Tags: javascript, validation, events, input

So far I use this to call the function:

```
 document.getElementById("dzCalculator").addEventListener("keydown", isNumberKey);
   function isNumberKey(txt, evt) {
      let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode == 46) {
          evt.preventDefault();
        //Check if the text already contains the . character
        if (txt.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (charCode > 31 &&
          (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

But unfortunately I get errors: Uncaught TypeError: evt is undefined

I am still very much in the learning phase, so I am not seeing what I am missing yet. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: The listener passes only the event to the callback so in your case `txt` is holding the event and `evt` is undefined.

Comment: Ok, I think I get that, what is the fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `addEventListener` passes only the event that triggered it to the passed callback so in your case `txt` is holding the event and `evt` is undefined.

You can extract the `txt` value of the input by using `evt.target.value`.

```
document.getElementById("dzCalculator").addEventListener("keydown", isNumberKey);
   function isNumberKey(evt) {
      let txt = evt.target.value;

      //...
```

As for the rest of your logic, there are some good answers already available:

[HTML text input allow only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

---

Since you are still looking for a solution to limit input I will offer this. Instead of controlling the keys allowed, you can validate the value after keyup. Using an `input` listener we can watch for changes and validate without seeing invalid characters show while also solving the overarching problem of maintaining expected functionality and accessibility without having to specify all key responses.

This snippet listens for changes using `input`. When triggered it extracts the current value using `event.target.value` and stores the current cursor position. It then recasts the string to an array using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `[...value]`. This array is then filtered using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)so that it only contains characters that appear in the `validKeys` string. It is then reduced back to a string using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) at which time it accounts for duplicate decimal points. If the resulting `editedValue` is different than the initial `value` the `evt.target.value` is updated and the cursor is set back to where it was (minus one because we have removed a character);

```js
document.getElementById("dzCalculator").addEventListener("input", isNumberKey);

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  const validKeys = '1234567890.';
  
  const cursorLocation = evt.target.selectionStart;
  const value = evt.target.value;
  
  let editedValue = [...value]
    .filter(char => validKeys.includes(char))
    .reduce((acc, char) => { return acc.includes('.') && char === '.' ? acc : acc + char}, '');
    
  if (editedValue !== value) {
    evt.target.value = editedValue;
    evt.target.selectionStart = cursorLocation-1;
    evt.target.selectionEnd = cursorLocation-1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="dzCalculator" value="" />
```

To accomodate negative values you can adjust `validKeys` and the `reduce()` callback thus:

```
const validKeys = '-1234567890.';
  let editedValue = [...value]
    .filter(char => validKeys.includes(char))
    .reduce((acc, char, i) => { 
        if (acc.includes('.') && char === '.' || char === '-' && i !== 0) {
        return acc
      } else {
        return acc + char
      }
    }, '');
```

Comment: ok, I did this but it prevents "." (decimal points)

Comment: Yes, the rest of your logic is in need of work `.which()` and `.keyCode()` are both deprecated. You might want to look at using [Number Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Comment: I am taking a look at Number Input, that's interesting. Seems like a lot more work and I am not 100% sure I understand it yet.

Comment: This is why I don't use that logic https://gyazo.com/793135b22aee23ad2d9077a586ced7f9 - and ironically, it is Firefox that is the fault! Otherwise I would. But maybe I will try and break into the warning box and fix it so it doesn't float and then use this undeprecated method that Firefox is not fixing!

Comment: @PaulDavis I believe my last edits provide a solution to the entirety of your question.

Comment: Thanks - your way does appear to work, but (I know, I can not win here) I can't seem to get the submit button to work now. *sigh* it never ends :P If you know what I could be doing to prevent the submit button working, I would love to know!

Comment: I fixed the code to work... but... even though I can submit, it submits no matter what is in the input. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have written pretty simple logic to allow only numerical input and restrict inputs with one dot only.

```js
document.getElementById("dzCalculator").addEventListener("keydown", isNumberKey);

function isNumberKey(evt) {
  let passCode = '0123456789.'
    if (passCode.indexOf(evt.key)===-1 && evt.key !=='Backspace' && evt.key !== 'Tab'&&
  evt.key !=='Delete'){
  evt.preventDefault();
  return false;
  }else{
  //contains numbers && dots
    if (evt.target.value.indexOf('.') >= 0 && (evt.key === ".")) {
      //check for multiple dots
      evt.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else
      return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='dzCalculator' type='text'>
```

Comment: Thank you for this... this is perfect, but I am crying because: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

keyCode is deprecated and so I am not meant to use it :( I feel a bit stuck!

Comment: Unfortunately this blocks all other key functionality including Backspace, Delete and Tab (necessary for accessibility).

Comment: How do you get it so that backspace, delete and tab are ok to use?

Comment: I have updated my code (assuming that your target browsers supports key and not keyCode). it allows delete backspace keys and numbers with one dot. i wonder why you want tab inside this as well since tab will shift focus to next element/control.

Comment: or you can merge my both solution in one like Mozilla documentation says to provide backward compatibility.

Comment: The problem is, once you start controlling key input you need to control **ALL** key input in order to maintain expected functionality and accessibility. Your edited code now accommodates the three keys I mentioned, but I can't use arrow keys to reposition the cursor, nor can I copy or paste, etc. etc.

Comment: yes but the question is to restrict key input apart from certain specific keys. for copy paste and navigation you always have mouse/right click. I am assuming user does have a mouse :) and restricting user on pasting invalid is another different question.

Comment: You should not assume that the user has a mouse, this is also the reason to never restrict `Tab` as it is a primary, non-mouse navigation key.